# mock config_opts['files'] seem to be ignored

Tags: centos, rpm, rpmbuild

I'm trying to create a fake /etc/hosts to set the hostname in a Mock-built RPM.  This is CentOS7 and the Mock/rpmbuild are not new enough to understand the new Fedora _buildhost macro.

So I configured a file thusly:

```
config_opts['files']['etc/hosts']="""\
127.0.0.1 build.machine.com
"""
```

This is at the end of my target specific config file.  Unfortunately this seems to be completely ignored.

I've looked at the `/var/lib/mock/<target>/root/etc/hosts` and this is identical to the build machine's standard /etc/hosts.

Anyone able to shed some light on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: OK, managed to get at least the file to be written but this seems to have no affect.  The ../root/etc/hosts is as I expect but the build host in the resulting RPMs is always the true hostname of my machine not the 'dummy' name that I actually wanted.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using 1.4.x version of Mock then it use by default systemd-nspawn container which overwrite some file. At least resolv.conf and may overwrite hosts as well. You may try `--old-chroot` option of Mock.

But if you want just overwrite hostname then you can put in config:

```
config_opts['hostname'] = 'my.own.hostname'
```

Comment: Thanks - looks like CentOS 7 is still using quite an old Mock (1.2.17) but it does have the '--old-chroot' option so perhaps I'll give that a try.

Comment: The new version is in EPEL https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL